# Created a CNAME record, but I'm forced to use the FQDN of the alias

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, domain

I created a CNAME record so that internal users could connect to our intranet, but it wont work unless I put in the entire FQDN. Here's how it's set up,

```
example    A       1.1.1.1
alias      CNAME   example
```

Example is the domain name of the device running the web server and alias is the name of the CNAME record I've created. I'm trying to get it so I can type in `http://alias/` and get to the main page of the intranet, but it wont work unless I type the FQDN. I can get to the intranet via `http://example/` without typing in the whole FQDN. I'm not much of a server guy, so perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a name on your computer, your system will try to guess if it's an FQDN or not, and if it thinks it's not, it will apply a configured default domain to make it into an FQDN.

The payload of a `CNAME` record is by definition an FQDN, so when your system gets a name from there it already knows that it doesn't have to do any guessing (must not do any, even).

So it sounds like what you're trying to do is not possible.